# Why can't we modify an l-value reference from an r-value?

Tags: c++, rvalue, lvalue

You can have an lvalue reference on an rvalue, but the lvalue must be const. Look at this simple program:

```
#include <iostream>

int compute()
{
    return 7*4;
}

int main(int a, char**b)
{
    int val_copy = compute();
    const int& val_ref = compute();
    int&& val_rval_ref = compute();

    std::cout << val_copy << " " << val_ref << " " << val_rval_ref << std::endl;
    val_copy++;
    //val_ref++ error because it's const
    val_rval_ref++;
    std::cout << val_copy << " " << val_ref << " " << val_rval_ref << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Output (C++17):
28 28 28
29 28 29
```

both the `const&` and the rvalue ref point to an rvalue created by the function `compute()`. Although, we are prevented to assign a non-const lvalue reference to an rvalue why? It doesn't really make sense to me to have an lvalue reference to an rvalue unless a temporary storage is created, but if a temporary storage is created, why can't we just change it like we do with a regular r-value reference?

Comment: Can you explain, in detail, what you meant by "prevented to assign a non-const lvalue reference to an rvalue why"? Nothing in the code attempts to do that.

Comment: you can't do `int& val_ref = compute();` 

`cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘int&’ to an rvalue of type ‘int’
   11 |  int& val_ref = compute();`

Comment: my understanding is `const int& val_ref` creates a temporary variable, but it cannot be modified. my understanding is also that the rvalue reference creates a temporary variable that can be modified.

Comment: References don't "point".  They refer to.   But `value_copy` cannot be incremented because the `const` in its definition means it is a reference to to a `const int`  (i.e. the `const` applies to the `int` itself).   A little more formally [going more formal makes my teeth itch, in this case] you have converted the `prvalue` (which refers to the temporary holding the return value from `compute()`) into `lvalue` that refers to a `const int`.